# Holoviews charts not updating on widget selection

Tags: holoviews

I copied the code below from a separate post on creating widgets that update plots based on the selection:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import hvplot
import hvplot.pandas

import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh', logo=False)

import panel as pn


# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': np.random.rand(30),
    'col2': np.random.normal(size=30),
    'category_col': np.random.choice(['category1', 'category2'], size=30)
})

# create widget to select category
category = pn.widgets.Select(options=['category1', 'category2'])

# function that returns a plot depending on the category selected
@pn.depends(category)
def get_plot(category):
    df_selected = df[df['category_col'] == category]
    plot = df_selected.hvplot.scatter(x='col1', y='col2')
    return plot

# show dashboard with selection widget and dynamic plot
pn.Column(
    pn.Row(category),
    get_plot,
)

# get value of current selected category
category.value
```

However, for me the charts do not update when the selection is made. Does anyone know what is going on here? I'm trying to execute this in a Jupyter Lab notebook on my local machine, no server. I'm running the following versions of these libraries:

holoviews: 1.13.3
hvplot: 0.6.0
panel: 0.9.7

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works fine for me in classic notebook using the same versions (holoviews: 1.13.3 hvplot: 0.6.0 panel: 0.9.7). Have you installed the JupyterLab extension? https://panel.holoviz.org/#installation

Comment: Hi James, thank you for the suggestion. I've installed the extension but some reason it still doesnt work in Jupyter Lab! I have tried in the classic version of the notebook and it works fine, so strange!

Comment: Probably some version issue or some number of JupyterLab and/or browser restarts needed.  Personally, I stick with classic notebook, so I'm glad that works!